# SQL: Getting Missing Date Values and Copy Data to Those New Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this seems somewhat weird, but this use case came up, and I have been somewhat struggling trying to figure out how to come about a solution. Let's say I have this data set:

| date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 50 | 2 |
| 2020-01-04 | 23 | 5 |
| 2020-01-07 | 14 | 8 |

My goal is to try and fill in the gap between the two dates while copying whatever values were from the date before it. So for example, the data output I would want is:

| date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 50 | 2 |
| 2020-01-02 | 50 | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 | 50 | 2 |
| 2020-01-04 | 23 | 5 |
| 2020-01-05 | 23 | 5 |
| 2020-01-06 | 23 | 5 |
| 2020-01-07 | 14 | 8 |

Not sure if this is something I can do with SQL but would definitely take any suggestions.

Comment: So far I have ben trying to use temp tables and some looping of sorts, but I am not the best recursive developer and break a lot of things lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to use the window function `lead()` in concert with an ad-hoc tally table if you don't have a calendar table (highly suggested).

**Example**

```
;with cte as ( 
Select * 
      ,nrows = datediff(day,[date],lead([date],1,[date]) over (order by [date]))
 From YourTable A
)
Select date = dateadd(day,coalesce(N-1,0),[date])
      ,value1
      ,value2
 From  cte A
 left Join (Select Top 1000 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1 ) B
   on N<=nRows
```

**Results**

```
date        value1  value2
2020-01-01  50      2
2020-01-02  50      2
2020-01-03  50      2
2020-01-04  23      5
2020-01-05  23      5
2020-01-06  23      5
2020-01-07  14      8
```

EDIT:  If you have a calendar table

```
Select Date = coalesce(B.Date,A.Date)
      ,value1
      ,value2
 From (
        Select Date
              ,value1
              ,value2
              ,Date2 = lead([date],1,[date]) over (order by [date])     
         From  YourTable A
      ) A
  left Join  CalendarTable B on B.Date >=A.Date and B.Date< A.Date2
```

Comment: oh this is really cool! Yeah I do have a calendar table thankfully, so let me play around with this code.

Comment: @MrTNader with a calendar table just JOIN where calDate is between Date and lead Date

Comment: @MrTNader See EDIT if you have a calendar table

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed and solved my issue way faster than what I was doing before. Going to remember something like this. Marked the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `CROSS APPLY`. I am not sure how you are determining what range you want from the table, but you can easily override my guess by explicitly defining `@s` and `@e`:

```
DECLARE @s date, @e date;

SELECT @s = MIN(date), @e = MAX(date) FROM dbo.TheTable;

;WITH d(d) AS
(
  SELECT @s UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,d) FROM d
  WHERE d < @e
)
SELECT d.d, x.value1, x.value2
FROM d CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP (1) value1, value2
  FROM dbo.TheTable 
    WHERE date <= d.d
    AND value1 IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY date DESC
) AS x
-- OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767) -- if date range can be > 100 days but < 89 years
-- OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)     -- if date range can be > 89 years
```

If you don't like the recursive CTE, you could easily use a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) (but presumably you'd still need a way to define the overall date range you're after as opposed to *all of time*).

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4123d8eb90071eb37694afa8dbc31679)

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server you can make a cursor, which iterates over the dates. If it finds values for a given date, it takes those and stores them for later. in the next iteration it can then take the stored values, in case there are no values in the database

Comment: don't need cursor to do this

Comment: Yes, you _can_ do it this way, but it's kind of like cooking eggs with a lighter. Databases are optimized to work on sets, not in loops.